# Windows with efficiency with blue tint

Tags: windows

My house was built in Florida in 2008.  I am having a difficult time in replacing my windows as they have a blue tint.  I have contacted all the local window places in the area and they do not know of this type of glass.  I have several windows to replace and do not want to replace the entire house of windows.  I have also had the glass people come to my house to check it out.  Any ideas?

Comment: probably some type of UV shielding

Answer (score 1):

Exactly matching some particularly shade of tinted window will not be easy, even if you can identify the maker.

Your best bet is to find out who the architect was on your house. If your city planning department still has the drawings, they will have the architect's name on them. Alternatively if you know who the developer is they might be able to tell you the guy's name.

The architect will know where the windows came from and how to get replacements, if it is possible.